# Javascript form won't submit

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have been using the uploader as provided by http://www.hoppinger.com/blog/2010/05/28/file-upload-progress-bar-with-phpapc-and-javascript/ and have since applied it to [one of my forms](http://test.elitetradersgroup.com.au/broker-tools/amazon-upload/)  and whilst the progress meter works, the submit function doesn't fire on successful upload.

The full code of what I am using is below:

[JS](http://pastebin.com/VmR64YsT)
[get_progress.php](http://pastebin.com/TegqnGg3)
[uploader.php](http://pastebin.com/SQf9kmXG)

As far as I can tell, in my limited experience, this is the function that handles the submit:

```
postUpload : function(o_data)
{
    // Loop through every input and set json response in hidden input
    this.a_inputs.each((function(o_input)
        {
            var s_name = o_input.get('name');
            var s_value = '';

            if(o_file = o_data.files[s_name])
            {
                s_value = JSON.encode(o_file);
            }


            var o_jsonInput = new Element('input',{'type': 'hidden','name':o_input.origName,'value':s_value}).replaces(o_input);


        }).bind(this));

    // Make form "original" again by purging elements and resetting attributes
    this.revertSubmit();
    this.o_form.submit();
},
```

I noticed that the submit was `this.o_form.submit();` rather than `this.form.submit();` and checked it out and he has declared `o_form : {}` at the top of the class, so I assume that his syntax is correct but I have no real idea.

Prior to my implementing this progress tracker the form worked perfectly, so this has got me quite frustrated.

Essentially what has gone wrong, I can only assume that it's something as simple as a missing `;` or similar mistake.

If you get a `404` on the submit that means it worked. I have temporarily unblocked the page for troubleshooting.

As it may be relevant, my site uses WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the javascript wasn't adding the `APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS` tag to the form so I added the following `jQuery` after the initilisation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var id = jQuery("form").attr('id');

        jQuery("form").submit(function(){

            jQuery(this).append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS\" value=\""+id+"\" />");

        });

    });

</script>
```

And now it's all good.