# Can't move/fine APC Uploaded file

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, apc

As a bit of a follow up to [Javascript form won't submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678784/javascript-form-wont-submit/) (to view the code I am using visit that link) I am now encountering a problem that I cannot find the file that has been uploaded.

I have added `$files = apc_fetch('files_'.$_POST['APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS']);` to the top of my page and this is the output of `print_r($files);`

```
Array
(
    [theFile] => Array
        (
            [name] => tt1.mp4
            [type] => video/mp4
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php2BEvy7
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1050290
        )
)
```

However when I try to run the following code:

```
if (file_exists($files['theFile']['tmp_name'])) {

    $webinarType = strcmp($files['theFile']['type'], 'video/mp4');

    if($webinarType == 0) {

        $webinarFile = $fileTitle;
        $webinarTempName = $files['theFile']['tmp_name']; 

    } else {

        echo 'Webinar must be .mp4';

    }

} else {

    echo "No File";

}
```

I get the `No File` output.

I have ssh'd into the server and the file is not in `/tmp/`, `/path/to/public_html/tmp/` or `path/to/file/tmp/` all of which exist.

I have tried to use `move_uploaded_file()` but as this is executed on all `file` inputs I can't get the `tmp_name` dynamically due to my limited knowledge of javascript.

tl;dr version; Where is my file gone and how can I find it?

NOTE; This form did work before the APC intevention and I am running wordpress in case that affects anything.

Comment: Never trust the mime-type sent by the client.  It can easily be faked.

Comment: Duly noted, however the [live] page is hidden to anybody but employees. It's more to stop them uploading a pdf in lieu of a video and to ensure said video is iCompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this one on my own as well.

In the `progress.php` file (found on the other question) I modified the `elseif` statement with this:

```
elseif(($s_progressId = $_POST['APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS']) || ($s_progressId = $_GET['APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS']))
{
    // If the file has finished uploading add content to APC cache
        $realpath = realpath($PHP_SELF); 
        $uploaddir = $realpath . '/tmp/';
        foreach ($_FILES as $file) {            

            if(!empty($file['name'])) {

                $uploaded_file = $file['name'];
                $moveme = $uploaddir.$uploaded_file;

                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $moveme);

            }    

        }

        apc_store('files_'.$s_progressId, $_FILES);
        die();
}
```

That way I could iterate through the `$_FILES` array without knowing the name of the input. I noticed that it loops through a couple of times hence the `if(!empty())` however in hindsight it's probably best practice anyway.